Fluent Bit Splitting Multiline JSON Logs in Kubernetes (AKS with MuleSoft RTF)
I am using Fluent Bit to parse logs from MuleSoft Runtime Fabric (RTF) deployed in an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster. The logs generated by my application have a header, followed by some metadata like thread name and log level, and then a JSON payload. However, Fluent Bit is splitting the JSON payload by newline (\n), causing each line of the JSON to appear as a separate log entry in Elasticsearch.
stdout log
[2024-12-09 16:58:07.453] INFO  LoggerMessageProcessor [[MuleRuntime].uber.05: [slb-rtf-aks-new].slb-rtf-aksFlow.CPU_INTENSIVE @4d2de1ee] [event: c33528c0-b64e-11ef-be04-0215ddf489fc]: {
  "status": "alive"
}

entries in fluent-bit logs
[2024/12/09 11:36:08] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] excluded=/var/log/containers/mule-clusterip-service-5fb85849cf-274vg_rtf_mule-clusterip-service-0e178a7a2aa150a6da237a6cde996688cd7c42f2120ff5adc3f2c858cde82a66.log
[2024/12/09 11:36:08] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] excluded=/var/log/containers/slb-rtf-aks-new-65bcf5f4f4-tvtjc_ORG_ID_anypoint-monitoring-6f50734f5174b3710809d8fe3ae1a5e07dc8e249d948ec89413a7d21f0ad163f.log
[2024/12/09 11:36:08] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] scan_blog add(): dismissed: /var/log/containers/slb-rtf-aks-new-65bcf5f4f4-tvtjc_ORG_ID_app-63550b94030d594da8ca0f2288359272aa9c061a2b3c2ae8ceff55afff0a007d.log, inode 4387407
[2024/12/09 11:36:08] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] scan_blog add(): dismissed: /var/log/containers/slb-rtf-aks-new-65bcf5f4f4-tvtjc_ORG_ID_init-8b2f1341fc8719f7d592f93ecebdcb1b298940d8247fb07376806ce31a6da266.log, inode 4387388
[2024/12/09 11:36:08] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] 0 new files found on path '/var/log/containers/*.log'
[2024/12/09 11:36:15] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] inode=4387407, /var/log/containers/slb-rtf-aks-new-65bcf5f4f4-tvtjc_ORG_ID_app-63550b94030d594da8ca0f2288359272aa9c061a2b3c2ae8ceff55afff0a007d.log, events: IN_MODIFY
[2024/12/09 11:36:15] [ info] [filter:multiline:multiline.0] created new multiline stream for tail.0_kube.var.log.containers.slb-rtf-aks-new-65bcf5f4f4-tvtjc_ORG_ID_app-63550b94030d594da8ca0f2288359272aa9c061a2b3c2ae8ceff55afff0a007d.log
[2024/12/09 11:36:15] [debug] [filter:multiline:multiline.0] Created new ML stream for tail.0_kube.var.log.containers.slb-rtf-aks-new-65bcf5f4f4-tvtjc_ORG_ID_app-63550b94030d594da8ca0f2288359272aa9c061a2b3c2ae8ceff55afff0a007d.log
[2024/12/09 11:36:15] [debug] [filter:kubernetes:kubernetes.1] Send out request to API Server for pods information
[2024/12/09 11:36:15] [debug] [http_client] not using http_proxy for header
[2024/12/09 11:36:15] [debug] [http_client] server kubernetes.default.svc:443 will close connection #88
[2024/12/09 11:36:15] [debug] [filter:kubernetes:kubernetes.1] Request (ns=ORG_ID, pod=slb-rtf-aks-new-65bcf5f4f4-tvtjc) http_do=0, HTTP Status: 200
[2024/12/09 11:36:15] [debug] [filter:kubernetes:kubernetes.1] could not merge JSON, root_type=3
[2024/12/09 11:36:15] [debug] [task] created task=0x7f030d6384e0 id=0 OK
[2024/12/09 11:36:15] [debug] [output:es:es.0] task_id=0 assigned to thread #0
{"create":{"_index":"*****-2024.12"}}
{"@timestamp":"2024-12-09T11:36:15.016Z","time":"2024-12-09T11:36:15.016955327Z","stream":"stdout","logtag":"F","log":"[2024-12-09 11:36:14.969] INFO  LoggerMessageProcessor [[MuleRuntime].uber.809: [slb-rtf-aks-new].slb-rtf-aksFlow.CPU_INTENSIVE @5bba7646] [event: cc4eb160-b621-11ef-bdc5-5afa9c807615]: {","kubernetes":{"pod_name":"slb-rtf-aks-new-65bcf5f4f4-tvtjc","namespace_name":"ORG_ID","pod_id":"37e3de46-c5ae-45bb-be22-316a08d60ef4","labels":{"am-org-id":"eb34a0c7-4457-421d-8fbc-543704629b56","app":"slb-rtf-aks-new","environment":"ORG_ID","name":"slb-rtf-aks-new","organization":"9357e0d4-ca00-43fe-85fe-f19e0c46badb","pod-template-hash":"65bcf5f4f4","root-org-id":"eb34a0c7-4457-421d-8fbc-543704629b56","rtf_mulesoft_com/disableAmLogForwarding":"true","rtf_mulesoft_com/generation":"3af3e3c0d051d9367963c3bba48f3c16","rtf_mulesoft_com/id":"bf57d697-21f6-4b08-9f51-cdb5b2d14abc","type":"MuleApplication"},"host":"aks-mulesoftpool-36227775-vmss000002","pod_ip":"10.244.2.129","container_name":"app","docker_id":"63550b94030d594da8ca0f2288359272aa9c061a2b3c2ae8ceff55afff0a007d","container_hash":"rtf-runtime-registry.kprod.msap.io/mulesoft/poseidon-runtime-4.6.9@sha256:941784f7ee4188f69a58abd7671eda01c099dc09b4ce85d46c6bfc1ba4f7ecbd","container_image":"rtf-runtime-registry.kprod.msap.io/mulesoft/poseidon-runtime-4.6.9:11-java17"}}
{"create":{"_index":"*****-2024.12"}}
{"@timestamp":"2024-12-09T11:36:15.016Z","time":"2024-12-09T11:36:15.016999127Z","stream":"stdout","logtag":"F","log":"  \"status\": \"alive\"","kubernetes":{"pod_name":"slb-rtf-aks-new-65bcf5f4f4-tvtjc","namespace_name":"ORG_ID","pod_id":"37e3de46-c5ae-45bb-be22-316a08d60ef4","labels":{"am-org-id":"eb34a0c7-4457-421d-8fbc-543704629b56","app":"slb-rtf-aks-new","environment":"ORG_ID","name":"slb-rtf-aks-new","organization":"9357e0d4-ca00-43fe-85fe-f19e0c46badb","pod-template-hash":"65bcf5f4f4","root-org-id":"eb34a0c7-4457-421d-8fbc-543704629b56","rtf_mulesoft_com/disableAmLogForwarding":"true","rtf_mulesoft_com/generation":"3af3e3c0d051d9367963c3bba48f3c16","rtf_mulesoft_com/id":"bf57d697-21f6-4b08-9f51-cdb5b2d14abc","type":"MuleApplication"},"host":"aks-mulesoftpool-36227775-vmss000002","pod_ip":"10.244.2.129","container_name":"app","docker_id":"63550b94030d594da8ca0f2288359272aa9c061a2b3c2ae8ceff55afff0a007d","container_hash":"rtf-runtime-registry.kprod.msap.io/mulesoft/poseidon-runtime-4.6.9@sha256:941784f7ee4188f69a58abd7671eda01c099dc09b4ce85d46c6bfc1ba4f7ecbd","container_image":"rtf-runtime-registry.kprod.msap.io/mulesoft/poseidon-runtime-4.6.9:11-java17"}}
{"create":{"_index":"*****-2024.12"}}
{"@timestamp":"2024-12-09T11:36:15.017Z","time":"2024-12-09T11:36:15.017003827Z","stream":"stdout","logtag":"F","log":"}","kubernetes":{"pod_name":"slb-rtf-aks-new-65bcf5f4f4-tvtjc","namespace_name":"ORG_ID","pod_id":"37e3de46-c5ae-45bb-be22-316a08d60ef4","labels":{"am-org-id":"eb34a0c7-4457-421d-8fbc-543704629b56","app":"slb-rtf-aks-new","environment":"ORG_ID","name":"slb-rtf-aks-new","organization":"9357e0d4-ca00-43fe-85fe-f19e0c46badb","pod-template-hash":"65bcf5f4f4","root-org-id":"eb34a0c7-4457-421d-8fbc-543704629b56","rtf_mulesoft_com/disableAmLogForwarding":"true","rtf_mulesoft_com/generation":"3af3e3c0d051d9367963c3bba48f3c16","rtf_mulesoft_com/id":"bf57d697-21f6-4b08-9f51-cdb5b2d14abc","type":"MuleApplication"},"host":"aks-mulesoftpool-36227775-vmss000002","pod_ip":"10.244.2.129","container_name":"app","docker_id":"63550b94030d594da8ca0f2288359272aa9c061a2b3c2ae8ceff55afff0a007d","container_hash":"rtf-runtime-registry.kprod.msap.io/mulesoft/poseidon-runtime-4.6.9@sha256:941784f7ee4188f69a58abd7671eda01c099dc09b4ce85d46c6bfc1ba4f7ecbd","container_image":"rtf-runtime-registry.kprod.msap.io/mulesoft/poseidon-runtime-4.6.9:11-java17"}}
{"create":{"_index":"*****-2024.12"}}
[2024/12/09 11:36:15] [debug] [upstream] KA connection #88 to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx is connected
[2024/12/09 11:36:15] [debug] [out_es] converted_size is 0
[2024/12/09 11:36:15] [debug] [http_client] not using http_proxy for header
{"@timestamp":"2024-12-09T11:36:15.017Z","time":"2024-12-09T11:36:15.017007227Z","stream":"stdout","logtag":"F","log":"ERROR StatusConsoleListener Attempted to append to non-started appender AnypointMonitoringFileAppender","kubernetes":{"pod_name":"slb-rtf-aks-new-65bcf5f4f4-tvtjc","namespace_name":"ORG_ID","pod_id":"37e3de46-c5ae-45bb-be22-316a08d60ef4","labels":{"am-org-id":"eb34a0c7-4457-421d-8fbc-543704629b56","app":"slb-rtf-aks-new","environment":"ORG_ID","name":"slb-rtf-aks-new","organization":"9357e0d4-ca00-43fe-85fe-f19e0c46badb","pod-template-hash":"65bcf5f4f4","root-org-id":"eb34a0c7-4457-421d-8fbc-543704629b56","rtf_mulesoft_com/disableAmLogForwarding":"true","rtf_mulesoft_com/generation":"3af3e3c0d051d9367963c3bba48f3c16","rtf_mulesoft_com/id":"bf57d697-21f6-4b08-9f51-cdb5b2d14abc","type":"MuleApplication"},"host":"aks-mulesoftpool-36227775-vmss000002","pod_ip":"10.244.2.129","container_name":"app","docker_id":"63550b94030d594da8ca0f2288359272aa9c061a2b3c2ae8ceff55afff0a007d","container_hash":"rtf-runtime-registry.kprod.msap.io/mulesoft/poseidon-runtime-4.6.9@sha256:941784f7ee4188f69a58abd7671eda01c099dc09b4ce85d46c6bfc1ba4f7ecbd","container_image":"rtf-runtime-registry.kprod.msap.io/mulesoft/poseidon-runtime-4.6.9:11-java17"}}
[2024/12/09 11:36:15] [debug] [output:es:es.0] HTTP Status=200 URI=/_bulk
[2024/12/09 11:36:15] [debug] [output:es:es.0] Elasticsearch response
{"took":43,"ingest_took":0,"errors":false,"items":[{"create":{"_index":"*****-2024.12","_id":"lnI0q5MB8y8i7NOBqPqL","_version":1,"result":"created","_shards":{"total":2,"successful":2,"failed":0},"_seq_no":387191,"_primary_term":1,"status":201}},{"create":{"_index":"*****-2024.12","_id":"l3I0q5MB8y8i7NOBqPqL","_version":1,"result":"created","_shards":{"total":2,"successful":2,"failed":0},"_seq_no":387192,"_primary_term":1,"status":201}},{"create":{"_index":"*****-2024.12","_id":"mHI0q5MB8y8i7NOBqPqL","_version":1,"result":"created","_shards":{"total":2,"successful":2,"failed":0},"_seq_no":387193,"_primary_term":1,"status":201}},{"create":{"_index":"*****-2024.12","_id":"mXI0q5MB8y8i7NOBqPqL","_version":1,"result":"created","_shards":{"total":2,"successful":2,"failed":0},"_seq_no":387194,"_primary_term":1,"status":201}}]}
[2024/12/09 11:36:15] [debug] [upstream] KA connection #88 to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx is now available
[2024/12/09 11:36:15] [debug] [out flush] cb_destroy coro_id=0

What I Have Tried

Fluent Bit Input Configuration:

I used the tail input plugin to collect logs from the pod's log files.


Multiline Parser: I attempted to use a MULTILINE_PARSER in custom_parsers.conf but still encountered issues. Here's my current parser:
 [PARSER]
     Name cri
     Format regex
     Regex ^(?<time>[^ ]+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr) (?<logtag>[^ ]*) (?<log>.*)$
     Time_Key    time
     Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z
     Time_Keep   On

  [PARSER]
     Name        docker
     Format      json
     Time_Key    time
     Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L
     Time_Keep   On
     Decode_Field    json     log


 [MULTILINE_PARSER]
     name          appParser
     type          regex
     key_content   log
     flush_timeout 1000
     # rules   |   state name   | regex pattern                 | next state name
     # --------|----------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------
     rule         "start_state"   "/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{9}Z stdout [PF] \[\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}\] (?:INFO|DEBUG|ERROR|WARNING|TRACE).*.\[\[MuleRuntime\].uber.*: \[.*.\](.*)/"  "cont"
     rule         "cont"          "/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{9}Z stdout [F] (?!.*INFO|TRACE|DEBUG|ERROR|WARNING)(.*)/"  "cont"


Updated Fluent Bit Config: Here’s the relevant part of my Fluent Bit configuration:
 [SERVICE]
     Daemon Off
     Flush 1
     Log_Level debug
     Parsers_File custom_parsers.conf
     HTTP_Server On
     HTTP_Listen 0.0.0.0
     HTTP_Port 2020
     Health_Check On

 [INPUT]
     Name              tail
     Tag               kube.*
     Path              /var/log/containers/*.log
     multiline.parser  appServer
     DB                /var/log/flb_kube.db
     Mem_Buf_Limit     50MB
     Read_from_head    true
     Skip_Long_Lines   Off
     Refresh_Interval  10
     Rotate_Wait       10
     Exclude_Path      /var/log/containers/*_kube-system_*.log, /var/log/containers/*_monitoring_*.log, /var/log/containers/*_rtf_*.log, /var/log/containers/*_logging_*.log, /var/log/containers/*_calico-system_*.log, /var/log/containers/*_dynatrace_*.log, /var/log/containers/*_ingress-nginx_*.log, /var/log/containers/*_anypoint-monitoring*.log

 [FILTER]
     Name                kubernetes
     Match               kube.*
     Annotations         Off
     Merge_Log           On
     Keep_Log            On
     Labels              On
     Kube_Tag_Prefix     kube.var.log.containers.
     K8S-Logging.Parser  On
     K8S-Logging.Exclude On

 [OUTPUT]
     Name                es
     Match               *
     Host                *****
     Port                *****
     Index               *****
     tls                 On
     tls.verify          Off
     HTTP_User           *****
     HTTP_Passwd         *****
     Logstash_Format     On
     Logstash_Prefix     *****
     Logstash_DateFormat %Y.%m
     Retry_Limit         6
     Suppress_Type_Name  On
     Trace_Error         On
     Trace_Output        On
     Replace_Dots        On
     Include_Tag_Key     Off
     Current_Time_Index  Off




Environment Details

Fluent Bit Version: 3.2.2
MuleSoft Runtime Fabric: Running in AKS
Kubernetes Version: 1.30.6
Elasticsearch Version: 8.x

Questions

How can I configure Fluent Bit to handle these multiline logs correctly and ensure the JSON payload isn’t split by newlines?
Are there better approaches or alternative configurations for handling multiline logs with JSON payloads?

Additional Information
If needed, I can share more details about my Fluent Bit setup or the logs being generated.
I've tried to apply multiline parser but without success.
I've also managed to only apply cri parser, but it also splits json newlines.

You used the rtf tag which is for Rich Text File. I assume you really want to use anypoint-rtf which is for Anypoint Runtime Fabric. I made the change this time.

Fluentd might be better suited for complex log structures like yours.

After some trial and error, I've figured it out what the problem was:

Had to update my rules in MULTILINE_PARSER to not consider time, stream and logtag
add parser flag in MULTILINE_PARSER and point to cri, which will parse every line and remove time, stream and logtag

This way the multiline parser will know which lines are to be merged.
